# How to adjust project layout for multiple phones using auto-layout?

Tags: xcode

I have finalized my project and my mistake was that I left auto-layout to be done at the end, now I'm stucked in it and can't find anyway through to finalize my project.
My project layout was made based on Iphone 7 plus "xcode 8" and has 7 viewcontrollers. when I try to put constraints, the whole project collapse.

Anyone can support with any best practice that can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what device size you are viewing in xcode. Its default for all size classes. If you want to make different layout for specific size class than you use variations. Check this tutorial https://makeapppie.com/2016/09/05/an-introduction-to-size-classes-for-xcode-8/